# Can't run robotframework project using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, robotframework

## I want to run tests using java & robotframework using maven.

I have inserted the dependencies of robotframework and the related plugin in the pom.xml file. 
I also tried inserting the dependency on com.sun for the **tools.jar** file, but running doesn't work.
As for the run setup I inserted a custom maven run with the base directory of the project and as goals I inserted `robotframework:run`.

I also tried to create an eclipse link by putting the correct path for tools.jar but it doesn't work the same.

This is the error that appears to me:

```
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.7 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191/../lib/tools.jar
```

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>AppQuality</groupId>
  <artifactId>EVD_Robot_01</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>EVD_Robot_01</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It could be helpfull to post at least the poml.xml .